# Generate a Confusion Matrix in Spark Scala implementing RandomForest of MLlib

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am implementing *randomforest* using *MLlib* of *Spark* in *Scala*. I want to generate a confusion matrix from the random forest algorithm.

I wrote the following code. But got nothing. How could I get a confusion matrix?

**Code:**

```
package org.test.newrandom

import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

//org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/MulticlassMetrics

object RandomTest {

def main(args: Array[String]) = {

  //Start the Spark context
  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("RandomTest1")
    .setMaster("local")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  // Load and parse the data file.
  val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "sample_libsvm_data.txt")

  // Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
  val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
  val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))

  // Train a RandomForest model.
  // Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
  val numClasses = 2
  val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
  val numTrees = 5 // Use more in practice.
  val featureSubsetStrategy = "auto" // Let the algorithm choose.
  val impurity = "gini"
  val maxDepth = 4
  val maxBins = 32

  val model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,
  numTrees, featureSubsetStrategy, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)

  // Evaluate model on test instances and compute test error
  val labelAndPreds = testData.map { point =>
  val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
  (point.label, prediction)
  }
  val testErr = labelAndPreds.filter(r => r._1 != r._2).count.toDouble / testData.count()
  println("Test Error = " + testErr)
  println("Learned classification forest model:\n" + model.toDebugString)

  MultiClassMetrics metrics = new MultiClassMetrics(labelAndPreds.rdd())
  println(metrics.precision()); //prints 0.94334140435
  println(metrics.confusionMatrix()); //prints like the following
  }
}
```

I am getting error in this line:

```
MultiClassMetrics metrics = new MultiClassMetrics(labelAndPreds.rdd())
```

It says- **not found: value MultiClassMetrics** But I added

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics
```

Comment: You could try replacing that line by `val metrics = new MulticlassMetrics(labelAndPreds)`

Comment: @ChristianHirsch, It works. (y)

Answer (score 0):

In scala, a variable can have a type ascription, which follows its name:

```scala
val metrics: MultiClassMetrics = new MultiClassMetrics(labelAndPreds.rdd())
```

Perhaps you copied that snipped from a java source file, where types come before the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it in SBT? If yes, you should add the dependencies to build.sbt.

```
libraryDependencies += "spark-mllib" % "1.4.0"
```

If this is the problem, it should still work with the scala shell.